# Transmit a ROS Video topic via video stream

Tags: gscam, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I receive a Video stream from my Android device using gcam, process the ros video stream with ar_toolkit and opencv amen want to stream it back.

How can I transfer a ros video topic to a Video stream? Gscam works in one direction only.

Thanks, enjoy the weekend

Poseidonius

Ok, more detailed: I plan to do the following chain:

```
   1                      2           3            4         5                 6  
Android  -- video --> gstreamer ---> ROS   ---> ROS     ---> ? -- video ---> Android
device      stream     server        gscam      ar_pose           stream    
                                                opencv2
```

Steps 1 to 4 works fine. I integrate some texts and augmented stuff in the video, but I have no idea how to transfer a ROS video msg into a video stream.

Any suggestions?
Best wishes

Poseidonius

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12184/transmit-a-ros-video-topic-via-video-stream/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2011-12-01

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2012-01-23**:
How are you streaming from android?  I assume its an ip cam app and if so could you post your GSCAM config line from your launch file so I could see how you got the image into gscam..

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-02**:
Where are you attempting to publish this video stream back to?

**Comment by [Yogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105/yogi/) on 2012-02-13**:
I wonder how difficult would it be to make gscam also work as a video sink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Isn't Android Java only or can you use Python/C++ too? If so, try looking at the simple [subscriber/publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) code (python/c++).

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2011-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2